# handling dynamic data of large or small size in div of fixed width

Tags: d3.js, graph, apexcharts

I have a dynamic data (number of views(count) v/s months) as my input to my multibar graph of apexchart library.

It works nice with small data. However, when I increase the size of data, the graph looks very bad(**shown in below figure**). I know the reason for this. It is due to the fixed width of graph. The width of bar is calculated based on width of graph and number of data items. But then how to fix this? How to handle large and small data in a fixed sized div?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : Add a slider to the parent div of graph (overflow-x:auto).

Step2 : Increase graph width based on your data. Do not keep it fixed. Create a logic that changes width of graph (not width of div that contains graph) based on data. Even if it goes beyond the parent div, that is fine as we have added slider only to deal with this.

Step3 : Add a logic for width of bars. In apexcharts, bar width is set in percentages. So,for example : width of bar for less data = 10 (10% of graph width). width of bar for more data = 30 (30% of graph width)

So this way, even if the width of our div containing the graph is fixed, it will be able to handle dynamic data of large and small sizes.

Solution example : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LzSNaYfzZNKQzOs8r9NVDqmQiFil-Xho/view?usp=sharing